# Clickhouse error while reading parquet using S3Cluster function instead of S3

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, google-bigquery, parquet, clickhouse

I'm transfering data from BigQuery to Clickhouse using Google Cloud Storage parquets. I'm export to parquets using EXPORT DATA command on BQ side like following (just hid variable values , script below just for demonstating purposes , i have no problem with exporting to parquets) :

```
    EXPORT DATA  OPTIONS (
             uri = '{gs_uri}*{full_parquet_filename}.{gs_format.lower()}',
             format = '{gs_format}' ,
             overwrite  = true)
             AS ( SELECT * FROM `{bq_project_id}.{bq_dataset}. 
   {bq_table}_intraday_{ts_date_str_bq_format}`
    WHERE event_date = '{ts_date_str_bq_format}');
```

After exporting I have a set of columns inside parquet that I can get using following sql script on Clickhouse side :

```
   describe table   s3(
    's3url',
    'access_key_id',
    'secret_access_key' 
    )
```

One of columns inside parquet has following type :

column_name - user_properties

column_type -

```
Array(Tuple(key Nullable(String), value Tuple(string_value Nullable(String), int_value Nullable(Int64), float_value Nullable(Float64), double_value Nullable(Float64), set_timestamp_micros Nullable(Int64))))
```

Using following formula I generate one column with string type that can be parsed as json (on Clickhouse side), and furhter I can grab any value just using visitParamExtractString function on Clickhouse side. Formula is :

```
select 

            arrayMap(x -> 'user_properties_'||(tupleElement(x, 1)) , user_properties ) as us_pr_key 
            ,arrayMap(x -> tupleElement(tupleElement(x, 2),1) , user_properties ) as us_pr_value_string 
            ,arrayMap(x -> tupleElement(tupleElement(x, 2),2) , user_properties ) as us_pr_value_int 
            ,arrayMap(x -> tupleElement(tupleElement(x, 2),3) , user_properties ) as us_pr_value_float
            ,arrayMap(x -> tupleElement(tupleElement(x, 2),4) , user_properties ) as us_pr_value_double

            ,arrayMap((a,b,c,d) -> 
                                coalesce(toString(a),toString(b),toString(c),toString(d)) ,
                                                   us_pr_value_string,
                                                   us_pr_value_int,
                                                   us_pr_value_float,
                                                   us_pr_value_double )                                as us_pr_filled_value
            ,arrayMap((a,b) -> 
                                ('{'||'"'||toString(a)||'"'||':'||'"'||toString(b)||'"'||'}') ,
                                                   us_pr_key,
                                                   us_pr_filled_value )                                as us_pr_key_value 
            ,'{'||arrayStringConcat(us_pr_key_value,', ')||'}' as us_pr_json
from 
s3(
    's3url',
    'access_key_id',
    'secret_access_key' 
    )
```

Example of generated value is following :

```
{{"user_properties_user_pseudo_id":"123122131241234"},{"user_properties_custom_client_id":"23123124332432"}}
```

Issue is when I want to adapt the formula for Clickhouse cluster to impove speed of insertion using S3Cluster function instead of S3 I get an error :

```
SQL Error [8] [07000]: Code: 8. DB::Exception: Received from server_name.com:9000. DB::Exception: Column 'user_properties.key' is not presented in input data.: While executing ParquetBlockInputFormat: While executing S3. (THERE_IS_NO_COLUMN) (version 23.7.3.14 (official build))
, server ClickHouseNode [uri=http://server_name.com:8123/default, options={socket_timeout=30000000,use_server_time_zone=false,use_time_zone=false}]@-1742689150
```

This working well with standart S3 function for millirards of rows with no issues ever. Is there resolution without edit of script ?

I use s3Cluster the same way as specified formula except that I specify cluster name like following :

```
..... FROM
    s3Cluster(
    'clickhouse_cluster_name',
    's3url',
    'access_key_id',
    'secret_access_key' 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable `flatten_nested` setting, in versions before 23.8 `Array(Tuple)` can be flatten in some cases as `Nested` type and it can cause some issues. Also worth trying newer versions like 23.8 and higher.